# Import error: no module name 'pip' on Arch

Tags: linux, pip, archlinux

I'm trying to install something with pip but everytime I execute it I get that error and I tried installing it with `pacman` and didn't work; also wanted to try securely downloading `get-pip.py` but I read that it may not be a good idea on Arch and I don't know if any of you have a solution I can try; this is the whole traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==7.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-18.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
ImportError: No module named 'pip'
```

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: I don't get anything; a blank line. @Rao

Comment: how about the output of `which pip`?

Comment: /usr/bin/pip @Rao

Comment: what is your os? can you re-try after upgrading the pip?

Comment: Have you tried `python -m pip` or `python3 -m pip`? Alternatively, see if `python -m ensurepip` works (possibly with `sudo` prepended).

Comment: @Rao it's arch, already did, still the same.

Comment: @Evert Got the same error (no module named pip) with the first two ones and `ensurepip` threw me this `Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
`

and a `Requeriment already satisfied after that`

Comment: Oh, @Evert after the `ensurepip` I upgraded it and it started working. Thank you.

Comment: I managed to get it working with `ensurepip` @Rao thank you very much for your help too :)

Answer (score 10):

I was doing a search for how to get pip installed as well. Some posts suggested that pip installs by default since python 2.x. I went to /usr/bin/ and looked for pip. No dice. I found mention of

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

Running the above suggested that I needed to have root privileges. I typed sudo !! and hit Enter and was greeted with pip being installed.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of pip available on the arch repos uses python 2. You're using python 3. Give this a shot:

`cd /usr/bin`

```
ln -sf python2 python
```

Keep in mind this will globally change the version of python you're using.
You can always change it back:

```
ln -sf python3 python
```